# SQL Server 2008 R2 Periodically Does Not Accept Connections

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem about connection pooling on Sql Server 2008 R2 environment (OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 X64). I am periodically seeing this in Sql Server error logs:

> Event ID:           18056
>
> Description:     The client was unable
> to reuse a session with SPID 157,
> which had been reset for connection
> pooling. The failure ID is 29. This
> error may have been caused by an
> earlier operation failing. Check the
> error logs for failed operations
> immediately before this error message.
>
> SQL 2008 and SQL 2008 R2 failure id is :   RedoLoginException,              29

We have migrated to SQL Server 2008 R2 CU4, running on Windows Server 2008 R2, and the issue continues.  SQL Server is having a problem communicating with one of its domain controllers when this happens.

When this happens, SQL Server Agent produces these errors:

```
[382] Logon to server 'DBINST01\DBINST01' failed (JobManager)
[382] Logon to server 'DBINST01\DBINST01' failed (ConnUpdateJobActivity_NextScheduledRunDate) 
[298] SQLServer Error: 258, Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response [SQLSTATE 08001]
[298] SQLServer Error: 258, TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. [SQLSTATE 08001]
```

We checked the error logs for previous errors but the only error we can see is this error in the log files. What may cause this error and how can I investigate that?

Answer (score 1):

Please check:

2543687 FIX: Errors when a client application sends an attention signal to SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2543687/EN-US

The fix for 2008 R2 RTM is in CU 14 
2703280 Cumulative Update package 14 for SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Note that you could also apply SP3 for SQL Server 2008 R2, which includes all the CU packages since SP2.